# How to handle Spring Security Authentication popup in Robot framework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, spring-security, robotframework, python-3.4

How to feed the Username and password values in Spring security authentication Popup using Robot framework(python,selenium),as html body is blank and i am unable to inspect the elements of the popup.Please Suggest.

[Authentication Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5kwh.png)